# Add ID to each Row of DataFrame in groups of 2 - R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Simple question - but I need to add an ID column for each row in a dataframe, in groups of 2. The first 2 rows of the dataframe should have ID of 1, 3rd and 4th row of the data should have ID of 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `gl` in `base R`.  Specify the number of rows and the `k` as 2

```
df1$ID <- as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), 2, nrow(df1)))
```